# JumpSSh in Python get_cmd_output

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote server from a jump server. It connected to the remote server perfectly, but when I try to run a python script on the remote server, it says no directory found. Please help

```
gateway_session = SSHSession('host',
                           'unman', password='password').open()
# from jump server, establish connection with a remote server
remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session('host',
                                                 'username',password='password')

print(gateway_session.get_cmd_output('python /Folder/test.py'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to check where you are:

```
print(gateway_session.get_cmd_output('pwd;ls -alrth; ls -alrth /'))
```

That way, you know if there is indeed a `Folder` at `/`

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8628552/user8628552) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61398467/jumpssh-in-python-get-cmd-output/61401965?noredirect=1#comment108644725_61401965):

> all I needed was to was separate the commands with a semi colon and run them using the same `get` output command.

The OP adds:

> I just sshpass to a jump server from their, I sshpass to the remote on the same command in a shell script.

Comment: @user8628552 With the same case (upercase/lowercase) for the folder name? If yes, try and activate tracing in your python command (https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html)

Comment: I think I fixed it, all I needed was to was separate the commands with a semi colon and run them using the same get output command. Thanks for you help

Comment: @user8628552 Great! Using semi colon is what I used in my initial answer. I have edited said answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to run multiple commands with the semi colon, and also I’m trying to run a python that reads from a uart and print out the output but it doesn’t prints anything out

Comment: @user8628552 What complete command did you try when you said you fixed it?

Comment: I used print(remote_session.get_cmd_output(‘cd folder; python test.py’)

Comment: @user8628552 for a remote SSH session, I don't think so.

Comment: Do you know a better way to do a double ssh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212496/discussion-between-vonc-and-user8628552).